# Retrieving Values from Nested Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Using an application's API, I'm able to retrieve data as a JSON and put it in an array.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r($obj);
```

When I print the array, I see:

```
stdClass Object(
    [metadataList] = > stdClass Object(
        [metadata] = > Array(
                [0] = > stdClass Object([metadataName] = > category [metadataValue] = > RECIPES)
                [1] = > stdClass Object([metadataName] = > title [metadataValue] = > Easy Sugar Cookies)
            )
        )
)
```

I need to set a variable equal to the title metadata value ("Easy Sugar Cookies"), but I'm having some trouble.

Here's where I am so far, but I'm not having any luck figuring out how to specify the specific metadataValue key, since there is more than one in the array.

```
$title = array_search('description',($obj->{'metadataList'}->{'metadata'}));
```

Comment: if i'm not mistaken , `array_search` won't help you because that string is in an Object.

Comment: Do you mean get the title value?

Comment: So you jsut want that value?  .. Or do you need all values that might be a title?


`$obj->metadataList->metadata[1]->metadataValue`  (direct)

or (expensive)


`foreach($obj->metadataList->metadata as $meta)
{
 if($meta->metadatavalue == ...
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is you have want...

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$value = '';
  foreach($obj['metadataList']['metaData'] as $metadata) {
  if($metadata['metadataName'] === 'someName') {
    $value = $metadata['metadataValue'];
    break;
  }
   continue ;

}
```

Comment: The `continue` statement is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

`$obj->{'metadataList'}->{'metadata'}` is an array of *objects*, not of strings. Hence `array_search(string, array)` won't work (apart from the fact, that there is no string `description` in this array/object structure).

I suggest you parse the data as array instead (object works fine as well though) and simply iterate over the array:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$value = '';
foreach($obj['metadataList']['metaData'] as $metadata) {
    if($metadata['metadataName'] === 'someName') {
        $value = $metadata['metadataValue'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(($obj->{'metadataList'}->{'metadata'}) as $sub_object)
{
 if(($sub_object->{'metadataName'}) == "title")
  return ($sub_object->{'metadataName'}->{'metadataValue'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head

```
$originalValue = "";
foreach($obj->metadataList->metadata as $index=>$metadataInfo){
  if($metadataInfo->metadataName =="title"){
    $originalValue = $obj->metadataList->metadata[$index]->metadataValue;
    $obj->metadataList->metadata[$index]->metadataValue = "hi big boy";
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are in control of the output of the object then make the metadata an Associative array then you can reference it as

    $title = $obj->metadataList->metadata["title"];